# Python functions don't have access to global variable?

Tags: python, function, scope, global

I'm familiar with other languages like Java and JS and just learnt Python and what is confusing me is this here:

```
upper_case = 0
lower_case = 0

s = "Hello"

def upper_lower(s):
    for c in s:
        if c.islower():
            lower_case += 1
        elif c.isupper():
            upper_case += 1
    print(upper_case, lower_case)
```

But I always get an error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'upper_case' referenced before assignment`
What does it mean "references before assignment"? But I already declare this variable before global??

Comment: Can we see how you call the function too please?

Comment: You can read it in [Official document](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).

Comment: upper_lower(s) or upper_lower("Hello")

Comment: See also https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
s = "Hello"

def upper_lower(s):
    upper_case = 0
    lower_case = 0
    for c in s:
        if c.islower():
            lower_case += 1
        elif c.isupper():
            upper_case += 1
    print(upper_case, lower_case)
```

or as mentioned with `global` keyword

Answer (score 0):

Inside a function, you need to use the `global` keyword.

```py
upper_case = 0
lower_case = 0

s = "Hello"

def upper_lower(s):
    global upper_case
    global lower_case
    for c in s:
        if c.islower():
            lower_case += 1
        elif c.isupper():
            upper_case += 1
    print(upper_case, lower_case)
```

Comment: Ah thank you! I didn't know about that. Is there a reason why it does not work if I don't mention global in the function??

Comment: You can access on reading but you need to use the `global` keyword to tell Python that you are not declaring a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You must add global

```
upper_case = 0
lower_case = 0

s = "Hello"

def upper_lower(s):

    global upper_case
    global  lower_case

    for c in s:
        if c.islower():
            lower_case += 1
        elif c.isupper():
            upper_case += 1
    print(upper_case, lower_case)


upper_lower(s)
```

Result

```
1 4
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is because you are trying to do the following operation: `lower_case += 1`, which is the same as `lower_case = lower_case +1`. As `lower_case` has not an initial value, this operation can not be done. The way to solve it is by adding this two lines:

```
    upper_case = 0
    lower_case = 0
```

You should do:

```
upper_case = 0
lower_case = 0

s = "Hello"

def upper_lower(s):
    upper_case = 0
    lower_case = 0
    for c in s:
        if c.islower():
            lower_case += 1
        elif c.isupper():
            upper_case += 1
    print(upper_case, lower_case)

upper_lower(s)
```

Comment: You might want to get rid of the numbers before the function definition, they are not needed.